# The import com.wordnik cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I'm very new to Android apps, and am learning as I go.  So, please be specific if you give an answer.

I build a simple Android test app using eclipse Juno ADT.  It works beautifully!  So the next step was to add a call to the WordNik API.

I installed the WordNik Java API which installed the following libraries:

> target>wordnik-java-client-1.0.0.jar
>
> target>wordnik-java-client-1.0.0-tests.jar
>
> target>lib>jackson-annotation-2.1.4.jar
>
> target>lib>... 7 more jar files

I added the libraries to the Build Path via
Project > Properties > Add External Jars

Now, when the add the import to my code:

```
import com.wordnik.client.api.*;
import com.wordnik.client.model.*;
```

I get errors "The import com.wordnik cannot be resolved.

I have tried recommendations I've seen for other such errors such as

Project > clean

Double checking my build path includes all the WordNik jar files

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Think you're missing the .*

e.g. `import com.wordnik.client.model.*;`

Comment: Nah, notice the italicized `import com.wordnik.client.model.` I think the * characters got parsed by SO as the markup for italics.

Answer (score 0):

With newer implementations of ADT, you shouldn't be using Add External Jars. Just put the JAR file in the `libs` folder of your project.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is going down this same rabbit hole...

There were a couple of reasons for my issue:

1)  Although Maven said the build was successful, it was not.  It turn out getting the source via the .zip files as some suggested does not always work.  You should use the Git command:

Either  git clone https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-codegen.git
or      git clone git@github.com:wordnik/swagger-codegen.git
cd swagger-codegen\samples\client\wordnik-api\java
mvn package

2) Installing ALL the libraries causes conflicts.  The libraries to install are:

wordnik-java-client-1.0.0.jar
jackson-annotations-2.1.4.jar
jackson-core-2.1.4.jar
jackson-databind-2.1.4.jar
jersey-client-1.7.jar
jersey-core-1.7.jar

It would be nice is the wordnik documentation was just a little bit more explicit.